# LINQ New Columns as Reference to a column

Tags: linq

I would like to ask if it's possible in LINQ if i use a newly created column as a reference to another new column? Just like expressions in Datasets?

Ex.

```
var t = (from t1 in ds.table
        select new {
           c1 = t1.col1 + 1,
           c2 = c1 + 2 // is it possible?
         };
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do that. You can, however, write:

```
var t = from t1 in ds.table
        let c1 = t1.col1 + 1
        select new {
           c1,
           c2 = c1 + 2
         };
```

Comment: Why doesn't his example work? You're also referencing the first column. How is your code different than his?

Comment: @Hasan: The expression for `c2` in my example refers to the extra range variable `c1`, not the `c1` property of the anonymous type it's creating.

Comment: @coreleone_1218: It's not clear to me why you don't want to use the form I've shown in my answer then - it should work fine.